# telnetlib telnet.write() is not working as expected

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, telnetlib

I am trying to automate a task using python telnetlib. Here is my code:

```
    import telnetlib
    t = telnetlib.Telnet(self._ip_addr)
    # t.connect()

    if not t.expect(["User Name : "], timeout=10):  # Expect username prompt
        raise Exception('No login prompt is received')

    t.write(self._username + '\r\n')  # Send username

    if not t.expect(["Password  : "], timeout=10):  # Expect password prompt
        raise Exception('No password prompt is received')

    t.write(self._password + '\r\n')  # send password

    t.set_debuglevel(1)

    if not t.read_until("apc>", timeout=10):  # Expect prompt
        raise Exception('No command prompt is received')

    import time
    time.sleep(2)

    t.write("vt100\n")
    t.write("olOff 9\n")
    # t.close()
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '*'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '****'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '*'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '\r\n\r\nAmerican Power    Conversion               Networ'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv 'k Management Card AOS      v5.1.4\r\n'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '(c) Copyright 2009 All Rights Reserved  RPDU 2g   '

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '                       v5.1.2\r\n-------------------'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '--------------------------------------------------'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '----------\r\nName      : Unknown                   '

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '                Date : 01/10/2011\r\nContact   : Unk'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv 'nown                                   Time : 06:1'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '5:31\n\r'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv 'Location  : Unknown                               '

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '    User : Administrator\n\r'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv 'Up Time   : 85 Days 7 Hours 30 Minutes            '

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '    Stat : P+ N4+ N6+ A+\r\n\r\n'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '\r\nType ? for command listing'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv '\r\nUse tcpip command for IP address(-i), subnet(-s)'

Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv ', and gateway(-g)\r\n\r\n'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): recv 'apc>'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): send 'vt100\n'
Telnet(10.130.210.71,23): send 'olOff 9\n'
```

I am executing this code on windows. The problem here is the last command is not being executed.

Can anyone please suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Can anyone suggest me

Comment: Have you tried with `\r\n` instead of `\n` for the last commands? Some servers are very picky in this respect.

Comment: @mata, yes I have tried but no use

Comment: Try clearing read buffer before sending any command.

Comment: @saurabhbaid, Could u pls let me know how to clear the read buffer

Comment: do `read_very_eager()` is the command, it will read anything on the buffer without blocking the IO
so call `t.read_very_eager()` before calling `t.write()`

Comment: @saurabhbaid, still no luck

Comment: @pydev did you tried reading buffer after `t.write("olOff 9\n")` using `tn.read_very_eager()`. 
What does it prints.

Comment: @saurabhbaid, it prints nothing. No change in output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124622/discussion-between-saurabh-baid-and-pydev).

Answer (score 0):

as answered in comments, missing at the end:

```
t.read_until("apc>", timeout=10)
```